# can't get sacl of a file

Tags: file, security, winapi, acl

I want to know the the integrity levef of a file, but can't get sacl. GetNamedSecurityInfo returns 0  (ERROR_SUCCESS)  , which means
there is no error in execution of it but SACL still becomes 0x00000000. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
int GetFileIntegrityLevel()
{
    DWORD integrityLevel = SECURITY_MANDATORY_UNTRUSTED_RID;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    PACL acl = 0;
    int dw = 0; 
        GetNamedSecurityInfoA("C:\\8.docx", SE_FILE_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,  0, 0, 0, &acl, &pSD));
    {
        if (0 != acl && 0 < acl->AceCount)
        {
            SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE* ace = 0;
            if (GetAce(acl, 0, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ace)))
            {
                SID* sid = reinterpret_cast<SID*>(&ace->SidStart);
                integrityLevel = sid->SubAuthority[0];
            }
        }

        PWSTR stringSD;
        ULONG stringSDLen = 0;

        ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SDDL_REVISION_1, ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, &stringSD, &stringSDLen);

        if (pSD)
        {
            LocalFree(pSD);
        }
    }

    if (integrityLevel == 0x0000)
        return 0;
    else if (integrityLevel == 0x1000)
        return 1;
    else if (integrityLevel == 0x2000)
        return 2;
    else if (integrityLevel == 0x3000)
        return 3;
    else if (integrityLevel == 0x4000)
        return 4;
    else
        return -1;
}


int main()
{

    HANDLE curProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID sdv;

    HANDLE hToken = 0;
    OpenProcessToken(curProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SECURITY_NAME, &sdv);

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = sdv;  
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);


    int i = GetFileIntegrityLevel();

    printf("%d\n", i);



    printf("%d\n", i);
    CloseHandle(curProcess);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: There is pretty much no error handling in your code, at all. Almost any call can fail, but we have no idea, if that is the case or not. Please implement error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

you need use not [`SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx) but [`LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx)

example code:

```
ULONG GetFileIntegrityLevel(PCWSTR fileName, PULONG pil)
{
    PACL Sacl;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
    *pil = SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID;// default LABEL

    ULONG err = GetNamedSecurityInfoW(fileName, SE_FILE_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, 0, &Sacl, &pSD);

    if (!err)
    {
        if (Sacl)
        {
            union {
                PVOID Ace;
                PSYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE pLabel;
                PACE_HEADER pHeader;
            };

            err = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;

            ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION asi;

            if (GetAclInformation(Sacl, &asi, sizeof(asi), AclSizeInformation))
            {
                PSID Sid;

                union {
                    PUCHAR pc;
                    PULONG pl;
                };

                static SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY LabelAuth = SECURITY_MANDATORY_LABEL_AUTHORITY;

                switch (asi.AceCount)
                {
                case 1:
                    if (GetAce(Sacl, 0, &Ace))
                    {
                        if (pHeader->AceType == SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE)
                        {
                            Sid = &pLabel->SidStart;

                            if (pc = GetSidSubAuthorityCount(Sid))
                            {
                                if (*pc == 1 && !memcmp(&LabelAuth, GetSidIdentifierAuthority(Sid), sizeof(SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY)))
                                {
                                    if (pl = GetSidSubAuthority(Sid, 0))
                                    {
                                        *pil = *pl;
                case 0:
                                        err = ERROR_SUCCESS;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        LocalFree(pSD);
    }

    return err;
}
```

---

despite that `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE` is located in SACL - `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` not return this `ACE` - it filter SACL and remove this ACE type from output. only `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` return this ACE type - SACL also filtered, and removed all ACEs, except this type. if we want got not filtered SACL as is - need use both flags - `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`.

in most case files/folders have no mandatory label at all. in  this case by default - `SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID` assumed. so algorithm is next - we query label with `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`

- if file have no SACL at all - we got NULL Sacl in output - so by
  default `SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID`
- if file have SACL but without label - we got empty Sacl in output
  `(Sacl != NULL && AceCount == 0)` - again
  `SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID` by default
- if file have mandatory label - we must got Sacl with `AceCount == 1` -
  need extract RID form this ACE

also for [`SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Right required to query: ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY
>
> Right required to set: ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY
>
> To read the SACL from the security descriptor, the calling process
>   must have been granted ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access when the handle
>   was opened. The proper way to get this access is to enable the
>   SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege in the caller's current token, open the
>   handle for ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access, and then disable the
>   privilege

but for got [`LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx) we not need have/enable any privileges

> Right required to query: READ_CONTROL
>
> Right required to set: WRITE_OWNER

Comment: Apart from making the code a bit simpler, does `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` provide any other benefit?  For example, does it mean that you don't need elevated privileges?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - really not much info. almost most files have no explicit label - so by default - `MEDIUM`. some files, say in `Users\<UserName>\AppData\LocalLow` have `LOW` - for LowIntegrity apps can write to this location. `HIGH` i view only in root of system drive (say `c:\\ `) while another system folders (like `c:\windows` - have no label - so `MEDIUM`) another drives also have no LABEL. this is faster useful for some utility program. and of course this nothing say about file DACL, read-only, etc

Comment: @HarryJohnston - "does it mean that you don't need elevated privileges" - yes, when we use it we **not need** `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege, unlike when use  `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`. but main - even if object have label in SACL - `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` -**not return** it.  **only**  `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` - return label. so no another way query it

Comment: Huh.  That's bizarre.  I guess it works like that for backwards compatibility

Comment: @HarryJohnston - no, I check SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION not return label ace. despite it on SACL. only LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION return it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I edit answer, for add more clarity about `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` vs `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` + fix code (was error in case empty (but not NULL) SACL )